# Linking/build vernacular/jargon - Dynamic linking methods

Tags: memory, makefile, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I'm familiar with general program memory layout (ie: text segment, data segment, heap, stack, etc), and am trying to find something similar to the description and diagrams here:

http://www.tenouk.com/Bufferoverflowc/Bufferoverflow1c.html

However, I'm trying to figure out three distinct cases, each involving the use of external libraries:

1. Static linkage of an external library at build time (ie: `libtest.a` in the `ldflags`)
2. Dynamic linkage of an external library at build time  (ie: `libtest.so` in the `ldflags`)
3. Dynamic linkage of an external library at run time  (ie: `libtest.so` **NOT** in the `ldflags`, but the library is loaded via `dlopen()`/`dlsym()` calls)

Can someone more familiar with this explain the memory layout to me? I'm especially interested in the distinction, if any, between cases `(2)` and `(3)`.

Thank you.

Comment: In case (2), the linking still occurs at link time, not build time. The stack(s) and heap arena(s) will be shared for all three cases. In case (1), the text and data sections of the library will be combined with those of your object files. In cases (2) and (3), each dynamically linked library will have its own text and data sections that may be relocated by the runtime loader.

Comment: Thank you. +1. Too bad it wasn't an answer. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the Solaris Linker Guide (at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E26507/index.html) to be very well written, and incredibly useful at explaining an immensely complex utility.

Diagram-wise, you might find those at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E26507/chapter6-93046.html#scrolltoc, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E26507/chapter6-34713.html#scrolltoc to be helpful.